# java How to resize the panel size dynamically

Tags: swing

I have a panel. I put a table into it. I added a function that increase the number of rows of the table dynamically. I want increase the height of that panel when I added a new row in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to specify a layout manager for your components and manage their position using that manager. 
I would recommend you to switch into same gui builder software which will help you understand what do you need to do to fix the position of your components. 
Very good for GUI building staff is Netbeans build in GUI designer, have a look [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) and check it out yourself